# Bisecting a fractal area

Tags: geometry, fractals

**Simple case**

It is well-known that if we have a regular hexagon on a plane, then every line that passes through the centre of the circumscribed circle bisects the area of the hexagon.

**Extension**

Assume we have a (2D) regular hexagon - like fractal, like the one in the image.

[image]

My question is: Can we claim the same as above? In general, I guess there is some dependence on symmetries, but I am not quite familiar with the whole concept.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Notice that your figure, as well as hexagons themselves, are centrally symmetric - that is, reflecting through the center point yields the same image. Thus, if you choose any line through the center splitting the plane into an upper and a lower section, the reflection through the center takes the upper section to the lower section and vice versa - thus the area of the hexagon in each must be equal.

Comment: My intuition agrees with your answer. What about the case where "self - similarity" is an approximate self - similarity?

Comment: @thanasissdr It depends on what you mean by "approximate self-similarity" - but the important fact is only that the shape be centrally symmetric, which is largely independent of whether the shape is self-similar or not. As long as none of the "approximate"-ness breaks the symmetry, you're fine.

Comment: I just borrowed this definition from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-similarity).